# WL.JsonStore is not initialized, When trying to build the cordova IBM Mobile First Application in Android devices and In Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I Followed the Following Link

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/#adding-jsonstore

I have Also added the JsonStore Plugin

Wl.jsonStore is not Initialized when trying to initialize the Cordova Mobile First application

```
 WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function (collections) {                
    alert("collections creted sucessfully");
     console.log("Collections created sucessfully");
    // handle success - collection.people (people's collection)
                                            }).fail(function 
    (error) {
alert(error);
     console.log(error);// handle failure                                       });
```

WL.Store is need to Initialized. Kinldy Help me out To fix this Issue.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a more significant code snippet showing the full initialization of the collections object. The error appears to be arising from wlCOmmonInit - can you share the full wlCommonInit function

Comment: yes Sure Check the Below code
var Messages = {};
var wlInitOptions = {};
var collectionName = 'people';
var collections = {};
var options = {};
collections[collectionName] = {};
collections[collectionName].searchFields = {name: 'string', age: 'integer'};
function wlCommonInit() {
 WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function () {
  alert("collections creted sucessfully");
  console.log("Collections created sucessfully");
 }).fail(function (error) {
  alert(error);
  console.log(error);
  // handle failure
 });
 loginApp.init();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Last, I Found my answer in the IBM TroubleShoot Site

Kindly Refer the Link:

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/ru/foundation/8.0/troubleshooting/jsonstore/

In config.xml, change the clientCustomInit property to true.
 In index.js file:
 add the following line at the beginning of the file:

```
document.addEventListener('mfpjsonjsloaded', initWL, false);
```

leave the WL.JSONStore.init call in wlCommonInit()

add the following function:

```
function initWL(){                                                     
  var options = typeof wlInitOptions !== 'undefined' ? wlInitOptions
  : {};                                                                
  WL.Client.init(options);                                           
}
```